# In ASP MVC routing, how do I specify an optional segment in the url that's not passed in as a parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

This may be a stupid question, but I can't find an answer anywhere. I have two very similar routes to a controller in an MVC site. One of the routes has ".html" appended to the action. Is there a way to specify that ".html" is optional? It's not useful in terms of the actual routing, it just may or may not exist and I don't like having separate routes just for this one difference.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Route1",
    "somepath/{action}.html",
    new
    {
        controller = "Test",
        action = "Index"
    });

routes.MapRoute(
    "Route2",
    "somepath/{action}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Test",
        action = "Index"
    });
```

Ideally, these two routes could be consolidated into one somehow. Something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Route",
    "somepath/{action}{*.html}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Test",
        action = "Index"
    });
```

Obviously, that doesn't work, but I'm curious if there is some way to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: does the routing work as you expected when your url has `.html` in it ? Or Is IIS trying to serve the file ?

Comment: The routing works fine as is, I was just curious if there's a way to consolidate them into a single mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could always specify a regular expression in your route to handle this, but I think the better approach is to just let the framework handle it.  There are more elegant solutions, but the quickest way to solve this is to add this to your web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```